# Rails: Getting the JSON object after making a post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, get

I'm a beginner Rails programmer and even though this question might be too easy, I love to know if it's possible and if it is how can I accomplish that?

My question inside the **index** how can I make a get request to a link and assign it's JSON response to an object that I will be later using on. The syntax(not correct) I had in my mind was something like;

```
people=Make_A_Get_Request("http://people.com") //It will return in JSON
@peopleName=people['name']
```

I know that it's not true but is there like any method I can apply in Rails like the one above to make a get request to a link and assign its JSON response to an object in my rails function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below

```
def index
  uri = URI('http://people.com/path/to/request')
  response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  #then you can play like data["name"]
  rescue Exception => e
   logger.info "Unable to do something due to #{e.message}"
end
```